# FB is not defined, trying to detect Facebook like button

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have this code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="snip" data-layout="button" 
    data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var page_like_or_unlike_callback = function(url, html_element) {
      console.log("page_like_or_unlike_callback");
      console.log(url);
      console.log(html_element);
    }

    function detectFBLike()
    {
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', page_like_or_unlike_callback);
    }
    detectFBLike();
});
```

And I have a JavaScript include which initializes the FB JS SDK like so:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
 FB.init({
        appId      : 'snip',
        cookie     : false,
        xfbml      : true,
        status     : false,
        version    : 'v2.1'
 });
};
(function (d) {
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk',
     ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {
     return;
 }
 js = d.createElement('script');
 js.id = id;
 js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

This generates an error: FB is not defined and the cause is this line

```
FB.Event.subscribe(
```

However in the console if I type FB it is recognized.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need to know if someone clicks the like button? I assume you read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496770/detect-when-facebook-like-button-is-clicked ? Facebook will detect that you do it and delete your app

Comment: WizKid see this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.3 the event does exist. Thanks anyway

Comment: I know it exists. Like gating is still not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy and they will delete your app if you do it. I work at Facebook so please take my word for it

Comment: you are calling `FB.Event.subscribe` before the facebook script is loaded, move it to fbAsyncInit which executes once the script is loaded